# Move Strings from database to array

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently building a multichoice quiz program in vb.net for a school asssignment. The Questions, Options and Answers are all stored in a table in a microsoft access file (.mdb). I have imported it as a data connection and created a data link including the table. My current problem is moving the strings in the table to an array so they can be displayed and compared (for auto-marking). It would be a great help to push through this barrier.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Someone may be able to offer a more efficient answer, but the way in which I go about this is as follows:

```
'create the connection, replace with the relevant connection string and database file   
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = db.mdb"
    con.Open()
'ready for loading, creating new datatables and sets to load the data from the database into.
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
' your query - change to what is needed.
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from TABLE", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
'fill into a datagridview, which you need to add to the form
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    con.Close()
'create the array, change x to how many entries
    Dim arr(0 To x) As String
'check the datagridview for where the data is being filled to. Adds the value of position 0,0 in the DGV to position arr(0), for example. first is row, second is column.
    arr(0) = DataGridView1.Item(0, 0).Value
    arr(1) = DataGridView1.Item(1, 0).Value
    arr(2) = DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value
    arr(3) = DataGridView1.Item(3, 0).Value
    arr(4) = DataGridView1.Item(4, 0).Value
    arr(5) = DataGridView1.Item(5, 0).Value
    arr(6) = DataGridView1.Item(6, 0).Value
    arr(7) = DataGridView1.Item(7, 0).Value
    arr(8) = DataGridView1.Item(8, 0).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but a couple of the variables specified have a "Declaration Expected" Error. Namely arr and con.

Comment: Marc, the code works perfectly fine for me. Check that you've placed the code correctly within a function, procedure, etc. and that the syntax of that procedure is correct.